# Proving Cauchy's inequality using Open Map Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Cauchy's Inequality States that:

> Let $f$ be analytic on $B(a, R)$ and let $r<R$. Then, for all $n \in \mathbb N$:
>   $$\frac{|f^{(n)}(a)|}{n!}\leq \frac{\|f\|_{\partial B(0, r)}}
> {r^n}$$

The Open Map Theorem states that:

> Let $f$ be analytic and non constant on a connected open set $A$. Then $f$ is an open map.

By using the Open Map Theorem, it's easy to prove the Maximum Module Principle, and, therefore, Cauchy's inequality for $n=0$. I was wondering: Since we can prove it for $n=0$, is it possible to prove Cauchy's Inequality by using the Open Map Theorem? Maybe by Induction?

I know some proofs of Cauchy's Inequality by using Integrals, However, I'm interested in knowing if there is a pfroof by using the open map Theorem.

Comment: I think it is difficult to get the precise constants this way. You may take the $n-1$-th Taylor-polynomial $P_{n-1}(z)$ with  'inductive' bounds and consider the max principle on $(f(z)-P_{n-1}(z))/z^n$ but because of the subtraction you will get a non-optimal bound. I don't know if there is a way to repair this.

Comment: Right now, I'm trying to prove the inequality for $n=1$. I noticed all I need to do is to show that for all $z \in B(a, r)$, $|f(z)-f(a)|\leq \|f\|_{\partial B[0, r]}$ since i can divide both sides by $|z-a|$ and then take the limit. I don't know if this is true.

Comment: No even for $f(z)=1/4+z-z^2$, looking at the unit disk, it is not true. The max abs value is around 1.76 and without the constant it is 2$.